# Function in model called automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

If I give the same name to a function in the Model of Codeigniter, that function gets called automatically when I load the model.

```
//controller
$this->load->model('my_model');

//model

class My_model extends CI_model {

function my_model {
}

}
```

In this case I don't have to call my model function like this

```
$this->my_model->my_model();
```

because loading the model calls the function as well.

Can somebody explain this behaviour? I haven't found anything in docs regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common concept in Object-Orientated programming. The function is acting as a [Constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29). The constructor is called when an instance of the object is created.

In PHP using the `__construct()` method is the advised way to declare a constructor for the class. However, in PHP 4, a constructor was declared using the class name, so:

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
>   function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
>   parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
>   by the name of the class.

In CodeIgniter, a model is a class. As you don't have a `__construct()` method in your class, PHP is treating your `my_model` function as the constructor for the class (as it is the same as the class name).

You may want to the following method to your model. This will stop `my_model` being treating as a constructor.

```
function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}
```

I'd personally avoid calling a method the same name as the class in PHP, as it can lead to this confusion! PHP's docs have some [useful information on constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).